# require file from gem

Tags: rubygems, capistrano, bundler

I have an example gem as from the Ryan [screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/245-new-gem-with-bundler)

It contains additional file `lib/lorem/capistrano.rb`. When I try to add `require 'lorem/capistrano'` to my `deploy.rb`, it gives:

```
`gem_original_require': no such file to load -- lorem/capistrano (LoadError)
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to call `bundle exec [command]` instead of `[command]`.